# Tensorflow image retraining with Inception3; where should new images be stored?

Tags: image, tensorflow, classification, python-3.5

So, I'm trying to retrain the image classifier model Inception 3 via their retrain.py code from their github ("https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py")
(The code is really lengthy, so I figured I shouldn't post it here)

However, I can't seem to figure out the proper way to store the images I want to use or in which directory I should store them.  I'm using Windows 7 with Python 3.5

Currently, I have the images in a folder called `Images` that are further broken down in sub-folders which are named according to the labels I want.

So as an example, It's something like `Images -> 'Cats'
                                              -> 'Dogs'
                                              -> 'Fish'`

where is Images is the main folder, and the subfolders are the types of animals.

The `Images` folder is at the location `C:\tmp\` which is the location where the Mnist tutorial autmatically downloaded the the Mnist digit dataset to, when I ran the mnist tutorial.py. So I figured I should store my images around the same location.

When I run the `retrain.py` from the above github link:

I get the following error

`Image directory  "" not found.
File "C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\image\imagenet\tf_retrain.py", line 668, in main
    class_count = len(image_lists.keys())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'`

I've looked over the code and tried to find the default value for `Image_dir` which is an argument for the function 
`def create_image_lists` (which seems to be where the script is looking for images,  but can't find it, or maybe I'm not understanding the code properly.

EDIT: I'm having trouble running python 3.5 via command prompt, so I can't use argparse.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to change the default folder path to your path (C:\tmp\Images) here?
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L903